# JavaScript File Upload inside iframe, resource URL changes on second use

Tags: javascript

I'm totally baffled on this one.

I have a simple File Upload form.  I created an iframe in the page:

```
<div id="upload_file_form">
    <iframe id="upload_frame" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

There is a button on the page that calls a function called `ShowForm()`, which sets this form visible for use.  Each time the form is displayed, I dynamically set the innerHTML of the iframe to contain a basic file upload form:

```
function ShowForm() {

    window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML =
    "<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='./Classes/UploadFile.ashx'" +
    "Select a file to upload, then click 'Upload' to continue." +
    "<input type='file' name='filename' id='filename' />" +
    "<input type='submit' value='Upload' />" +
    "</form>";

    document.getElementById("upload_file_form").style.display = "block";
}
```

It displays the file upload form.  I choose a file, and it uploads it.  I then set the form `display:none`, and we're done.  And it works, perfectly.  ***ONCE!***

If I click the Upload button again, it shows the form, sets the iframe innerHTML again, it displays the form, **it looks just like it did the first time**, I choose a file, click upload, and boom!

```
404 The resource cannot be found.

HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Classes/Classes/UploadFile.ashx
```

Somehow, `./Classes/UploadFile.ashx` has changed to `/Classes/Classes/UploadFile.ashx`

And I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> action='./Classes/UploadFile.ashx'
> ```

You have a relative path.

When you submit the form the URL for the current page is taken, the fragment ID and query string (if they exist) are removed, then everything after the last `/` in the path is removed, then `Classes/UploadFile.ashx` is appended to what is left.

When you initially load the iframe, then URL in the iframe is … something that you haven't told us.

When you submit it for the first time, it changes to `/Classes/Classes/UploadFile.ashx`.

When you submit it for the second time `/Classes/UploadFile.ashx` as the base URL plus `action='./Classes/UploadFile.ashx'` gives you `/Classes/Classes/UploadFile.ashx`.

---

Use an absolute path instead.

```
action='/Classes/UploadFile.ashx'
```

Or load the contents of the frame by navigating it to the desired URL instead of modifying the HTML of the document you have.

Comment: Indeed.  That leading "." threw it.  I removed it and it works fine.  Thank you.